# Deletar $_session ao sair do navegador

Tags: php, html, mysql

Opa galerinha, estou fazendo um painel de consultas com sistemas de sessions.
Estou com uma pequena duvida relacionado a ele...
Como eu posso detectar se o usuário fechou o navegador? ja tentei UNLOAD(); porem ele detecta quando o usuário muda de pagina, mas isso não quero.
Somente quero DETECTAR se o USUÁRIO saiu do NAVEGADOR para eu poder SAIR(fazer logout) da SESSION.

Segue o codigo:

```
    <?php
  //starta a sessão
  session_start();
  ob_start();

  //resgata os valores das session em variaveis
  $id_users = isset($_SESSION['id_users']) ? $_SESSION['id_users']: ""; 
  $nome_user = isset($_SESSION['nome']) ? $_SESSION['nome']: "";  
  $login_users = isset($_SESSION['login']) ? $_SESSION['login']: "";  
  $pass_users = isset($_SESSION['pass']) ? $_SESSION['pass']: ""; 
  $logado = isset($_SESSION['logado']) ? $_SESSION['logado']: "N";
  $tipo_conta = isset($_SESSION['tipo_conta']) ? $_SESSION['tipo_conta']: ""; 
  $pontos = isset($_SESSION['pontos']) ? $_SESSION['pontos']: ""; 
  // Pega dados novamente porem diretamente ao MYSQL
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=central_srblue', 'root', '');
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'central_srblue');
  $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_users='$id_users'");
  $dados = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $nome_user = $dados['nome'];
  $tipo_conta = $dados['tipo_conta'];
  $pontos = $dados['pontos'];

  //varificamos e a var logado contém o valos (S) OU (N), se conter N quer dizer que a pessoa não fez o login corretamente
  //que no caso satisfará nossa condição no if e a pessoa sera redirecionada para a tela de login novamente
  if ($logado == "N" && $id_users == ""){     
    echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>
          location.href='index.php'
        </script>"; 
    exit();
  }

?>
```

Comment: Uma possibilidade de detecção seria o cliente enviar uma mensagem indicando que o browser foi fechado ou então o servidor enviar ao usuário um session only cookie. Porém você não pode depender do usuário fechar o browser para encerrar um script, ou mesmo determinar uma ação. No caso da mensagem uma queda de energia, quebra da máquina ou falha de software impediriam o envio da mensagem. No caso do session only cookie os navegadores atuais possuem uma funcionalidade `continuar de onde parei...` que restauram session only cookie o que pode confundir sua aplicação.

Comment: Então unico geito é criando COOKIES? porem esses COOKIES podem bugar o painel certo? Oky vou aderir ao sistema de pontos mesmo, somente acessar tal função se ter determinados pontos... Obrigado maninho!

Comment: Quando vc fecha o navegador, as `SESSIONS` são excluídas automaticamente.

Comment: e Os dados da session? Porque quando eu dou logout deleta todos os dados e sai da session, somente permitido acessar o painel quando estiver com os dados na SESSION.